# Convert a column to 12 hour time format in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to convert time 08:00:00 to 12 hour time format like 08:00:00 AM format in snowflake.

Comment: What data type is the time? Is it a time data type or a varchar?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
select to_varchar( TO_TIME('08:00:00'), 'HH12:MI:SS AM' );
```

Check here for more information on date/time formats: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/date-time-input-output.html#time-formats